# Python: can I have a list with named indices?

Tags: python, arrays

In PHP I can name my array indices so that I may have something like:

```
$shows = Array(0 => Array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Sesame Street'), 
               1 => Array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Dora The Explorer'));
```

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: You should read the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) and esp. the section about [datastructures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) which also covers [dictionaries.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: To assist future Googling, these are usually called associative arrays in PHP, and dictionaries in Python.

Comment: Not exactly the same syntax, but there are a number of dictionary extensions out there which respect the order in which the key/value pairs have been added. E.g. [seqdict](http://home.arcor.de/wolfgang.grafen/Python/Modules/seqdict/Seqdict.html).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This sounds like the PHP array using named indices is very similar to a python dict:

```
shows = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "Sesaeme Street"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Dora The Explorer"},
]
```

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries for more on this.

Comment: Bit too complicated. I think the poster wanted dicts

Comment: This is actually a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @AndrewCase which, by the way OP is using nested PHP Arrays, is the most equivalent structure.

Answer (score 26):

PHP arrays are actually maps, which is equivalent to dicts in Python.

Thus, this is the Python equivalent:

`showlist = [{'id':1, 'name':'Sesaeme Street'}, {'id':2, 'name':'Dora the Explorer'}]`

Sorting example:

```
from operator import attrgetter

showlist.sort(key=attrgetter('id'))
```

BUT!  With the example you provided, a simpler datastructure would be better:

```
shows = {1: 'Sesame Street', 2:'Dora the Explorer'}
```

Answer (score 19):

@Unkwntech,

What you want is available in the just-released Python 2.6 in the form of [named tuples](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#new-improved-and-deprecated-modules).  They allow you to do this:

```
import collections
person = collections.namedtuple('Person', 'id name age')

me = person(id=1, age=1e15, name='Dan')
you = person(2, 'Somebody', 31.4159)

assert me.age == me[2]   # can access fields by either name or position
```

Comment: Of course, this can be simulated for older versions of Python (example: http://users.forthnet.gr/ath/chrisgeorgiou/python/TupleStruct.py )

Comment: Thats good to know about 2.6, looks like its time to upgrade.

Comment: Named tuples, or tuples in general, are **immutable**.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar: Nothing really is immutable. The trick is to create a list inside the tuple and change the value in the list. The tuple holds the ID of the list and it can't be changed. But the members of the list can be changed. think abt it.

Comment: @VB: It ***is*** immutable as a container: you cannot insert, remove or replace its members. NamedTuples are not fully equivalent to PHP's Array, even with your trick you cannot change its length.

Answer (score 9):

Yes,

```
a = {"id": 1, "name":"Sesame Street"}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `pandas` library has a really neat solution: `Series`.

```
book = pandas.Series( ['Introduction to python', 'Someone', 359, 10],
   index=['Title', 'Author', 'Number of pages', 'Price'])
print book['Author']
```

For more information check it's documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html.

Comment: I used named vectors in R a lot and was missing this when working in python. This looks like the closest analog.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking is about python dictionaries.There you can  named your indices as you wish .
For ex:

```
dictionary = {"name": "python", "age": 12}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has lists and dicts as 2 separate data structures. PHP mixes both into one. You should use dicts in this case.

Answer (score -2):

I did it like this:

```
def MyStruct(item1=0, item2=0, item3=0):
    """Return a new Position tuple."""
    class MyStruct(tuple):
        @property
        def item1(self):
            return self[0]
        @property
        def item2(self):
            return self[1]
        @property
        def item3(self):
            return self[2]
    try:
        # case where first argument a 3-tuple                               
        return MyStruct(item1)
    except:
        return MyStruct((item1, item2, item3))
```

I did it also a bit more complicate with list instead of tuple, but I had override the setter as well as the getter.

Anyways this allows:

```
    a = MyStruct(1,2,3)
    print a[0]==a.item1
```

Comment: This is a good example of how to ignore the semantics of a given programming language and re-create ones own notion of a solution.\