# Named dictionary in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, python-2.7

I did some research on how to use named array from PHP in python, while i found the following code example as they said can be done with dictionary.

```
shows = [
   {"id": 1, "name": "Sesaeme Street"},
   {"id": 2, "name": "Dora The Explorer"},
]
```

Source: [Portion of code getting from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178199/python-can-i-have-a-list-with-named-indices)

Reference: [Python references](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

But how could i adding a new value through a loop? While the references shown on how to adding single value by simply shows['key']="value" but i can't linking both of them. Can anyone please show me how to add the value into this dictionary through a loop?

For example:

```
for message in messages: 
            myvariable inside having two field
            - Message
            - Phone number
```

**Update**
May i know how could i loop them out to display after aped list into dictionary? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be adding the dictionary into an array like :

```
friends = []
for message in messages:
  dict = {"message" : message.message, "phone" : message.phone }
  friends.append(dict)
```

to loop again, you can do it this way :

```
for friend in friends:
  print "%s - %s" % (friend["message"], friend["phone"])
```

Comment: May i know how can i access it later on? I mean like loop them to display. Sorry, because i'm new to python and a bit noob :/

Comment: i meant like looping them to display or echo them.

Comment: Read the tutorial for [for-loops](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how you use the dicts in the array

Answer (score 1):

Effectively your example is a list of dictionaries, in PHP terms array of associative arrays.

To add an item you can do:

```
shows.append({ "id" : 3, "name" : "House M.D."})
```

`[]` denotes a `list`, or an array.

`{}` denotes a `dictionary` or an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can do (list comprehension)

```
message_informations = [{"message": m.message, "phone": m.phone} for m in messages]
```

If you want to assing an id for each message_information and store in a dictionary (dict comprehension)

```
{_id: {"message": m.message, "phone": m.phone} for _id, m in enumerate(messages)}
```