# Renaming list indices in Python - seeking explanation of code

Tags: python-3.x, list, range, indices

I am in the process of learning Python, which is my first real experience with programming. I have been working through a series of lessons found [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Loop_Control_Statements.html#exercise-3).

The lesson I am on is concerned with nesting loops. However, in one exercise they offer a solution to the problem by essentially renaming the indices of the list items. Keep in mind, this is not a dictionary being used. While these lessons have been going great, this one answer to the problem baffles me as there is no explanation of what is going on. Furthermore, I cannot seem to find reference to this technique anywhere else in the lessons series, or elsewhere.

Here is what the exercise is asking me to do.
1 "Write a program which uses a nested for loop to populate a three-dimensional list representing a calendar: the top-level list should contain a sub-list for each month, and each month should contain four weeks. Each week should be an empty list.
2 Modify your code to make it easier to access a month in the calendar by a human-readable month name, and each week by a name which is numbered starting from 1. Add an event (in the form of a string description) to the second week in July.

The first part was no problem. The second part was a bit challenging given the parameters, but the answer given was not what I expected.

I've seen explanations on stack overflow of using dictionaries to accomplish this sort of naming indices goal:
[Python: can I have a list with named indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178199/python-can-i-have-a-list-with-named-indices)

However, here was the solution offered:

```
(JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER) = range(12)

(WEEK_1, WEEK_2, WEEK_3, WEEK_4) = range(4)

calendar = []
for m in range(12):
    month = []

    for w in range(4):
        month.append([])

    calendar.append(month)
calendar[JULY][WEEK_2].append("Go on holiday!")
print(calendar)
```

Can someone explain how this works exactly? I find it odd that the month and week names do not have to be strings, but rather just variable names. I think each variable name is being assigned to each item in the particular range defined. However, I'm surprised that variable names can be used as the list indices. Once this is done, I cannot refer to an index by numerical value anymore. For example, I cannot use:

```
calendar[1][1].append("This is the first week of January.")
```

I am further confused by this because when I write a simple loop after the last line:

```
for i in range(12):
    print(i)
```

I get a print out of numbers 0 through 11 as usual, but not these variable names.

What's going on exactly, and how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a list of variables like this:

`(WEEK_1, WEEK_2, WEEK_3, WEEK_4) = range(4)`

is a way of storing multiple values to multiple variables. It is the same as doing this:

```
(WEEK_1, WEEK_2, WEEK_3, WEEK_4) = (0,1,2,3)
```

or this:

```
WEEK_1 = 0
WEEK_2 = 1
WEEK_3 = 2
WEEK_4 = 3
```

range(4) returns a list of integers from 0 to 3.

```
range(4) == (0,1,2,3)
```

In python, it is possible to write a list of variables as the left operand and assign values to them by writing a list of data on the right operand. In this case, the first variable of the list on the left will store the value of the first piece of data on the right, the second variable on the left will store the value of the second piece of data on the right and so on.

In your exercise, the months and weeks are only stored in memory as integers.
These integers have all been stored in variables whose names are representative of what each value depicts.

Contrary to what you have said, `calendar[1][1].append("First week of January")` does work. Technically, the first week of January is in `calendar[0][0]` because the indexes of lists start at 0. The reason for this is because as we stated earlier, `WEEK_1, WEEK_2` etc. are variable names in which integers are stored. Accordingly the same exact thing happens with the months as well. When you say `calendar[JULY][WEEK_2]` it is the exact same thing as saying `calendar[7][1]`, only now you've stored these numbers into more readable variables so the code is more representative of what it does and easier to read.

Comment: I see I had that index off by one in my example for the first week of January. I went back and tried `calendar[0][0].append("First week of January")` again. Before I received an IndexError saying 'index out of range'. However, this time I did not - so this leads me to believe I had another error in my original attempt.

Your explanation makes good sense to me. Is there now a way to print a list of these variables being used for the indices? I'm just trying to wrap my head around the whole idea more fully as I hadn't seen variables used for indices anywhere else. Thanks!

Comment: I guess where the confusion remains is that while I understand the assignment of `JANUARY = 0,
FEBRUARY = 1`, etc. I am not understanding why later saying `for m in range(12):`, I am referencing those variables, and not integers as normal. I get why JANUARY = 0, but if 0 = JANUARY, why doesn't this conflict later when we say `for w in range(4)`? I'm having difficulty grasping where this information is being stored. If I add `print(list(range(12)))` to the end of this code, I still get integers. Why does this reference a set of variables in one instance, but not another?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I now understand better. My confusion was that it appeared to me, that I was assigning the indices named variables. I now understand that I am just giving a name to the numbers and **not** the indices. The indecis are always integers.

I see this now because I can reference week two in January of the above code using any of the following:

```
calendar[0][1].append("Week 2 of January")
calendar[JANUARY][WEEK_2].append("Week 2 of January")
calendar[JANUARY][FEBRUARY].append("Week 2 of January")
calendar[WEEK_1][WEEK_2].append("Week 2 of January")
```

All of these are pointing to index [1] and [0]. I have not somehow magically affected the range(12) function I was calling.

Answer (score 0):

(JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER) = range(12)

**(WEEK_1, WEEK_2, WEEK_3, WEEK_4) = range(4)**

```
calendar = []
for m in range(12):
month = []

for w in range(4):
    month.append([])

calendar.append(month)
calendar[JULY][WEEK_2].append("Go on holiday!")
print(calendar)
```

This program is not running.