# Retrieving Element of a List with Name instead of n-th element

Tags: python

I am unsure how to gather different dataframes under "the same roof". I thought it might be a good idea to create a list, in which each element is a dataframe (if there is a more convenient way, please enlighten me). To give an example of how I created this list:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
tic_in = ['AAPL', 'AMZN']          # list for feeding url 

list_test = []
for ticker in tic_in:
   url = 'https://www.stocksplithistory.com/?symbol=' + str(ticker) 
   html = requests.get(url).content
   df_list = pd.read_html(html)
   df = df_list[7]                       # 7th table is what I want                    
   list_test.append(df)                  # append new dataframe to list
```

Now my problem: If I want to access any of these dataframes, I have to work with the n-th element. Speaking: If I e.g. want to retrieve the dataframe of 'AAPL', I have to:

```
list_test[0].head()
```

Is there a possibility to somehow give a position of a list a name? So I could avoid working with the n-th element, and instead work with the more direct way:

```
list_test['AAPL']
```

(Im new to this forum, thank you very much)

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary?

Comment: I haven't heard of this collection method via a dictionary before, I'm very new to programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: can I have a list with named indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178199/python-can-i-have-a-list-with-named-indices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
tic_in = ['AAPL', 'AMZN']          # list for feeding url 

dict_test = {}
for ticker in tic_in:
   url = 'https://www.stocksplithistory.com/?symbol=' + str(ticker) 
   html = requests.get(url).content
   df_list = pd.read_html(html)
   df = df_list[7]                       # 7th table is what I want                    
   dict_test[ticker] = df
```

Comment: I was exactly searching for something with the caracteristics of this dictionary, but I couldn't find it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you use a dictionary for this. Then you can simply do:

```
list_test = {}
list_test['AAPL'] = "foo"
```